# Почему webpack выдает You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type?

Tags: webpack, babel

Вопрос старый, как оказалось, но ни одно предложение решить его не проходит.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изначально выдает You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.

Пробовал добавлять в конфиг

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  process: 'process/browser',
})
```

Все равно не работает

Пробовал на всякий случай и отдельно babel.config.json создать

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-env"],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx", "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"]
}
```

Сам конфиг такой

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
    filename: 'index-bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-env"],
            plugins: ["@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx", "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"]
          },
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|scss|sass)$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
    }),
  ],
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack --mode development --watch",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.14.6",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "sass": "^1.35.1",
    "sass-loader": "^12.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.6",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^1.0.4",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.6",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "transform-runtime": "0.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.41.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: На какой файл ругается?

Comment: Кстати, тест для js-файлов у вас неправильный. Должен быть `/\.(js|jsx)$/`

Comment: Импортирую библиотеку компонентов с репозитория. На React. Там js и  scss файлы. В начале вопроса скриншот ошибки. И так на каждый js файл. Тест, да, что-то не тот. Но поменяв его, ничего не меняется.

Comment: Полное имя файла? Если он в node_modules, то у вас написано не обрабатывать его бабелем, а сам по себе webpack не умеет загружать jsx

Comment: импортирую библиотеку как обычный пакет. И да, exclude node_modules - это плохая получается идея) убрал.  Выдает  WARNING 
export 'default' (imported as 'React') was not found in 'react' (possible exports: __esModule) по всем js файлам. 
Попробовал добавить "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties" в babel.config.json . Результат тот же(